# Detect if a URI-protocol registered on client machine?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for a web-app to detect if a protocol (URI-scheme) is registered on the client machine? For example "spotify:" or "skype:".

Tried opening a URL in a hidden iframe - didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that it is not.

This would require a browser to be made indirectly aware of what applications the user has installed on their software, which is an unnecessary transparency and by virtue of that: a security risk.